# How to manage project with signed assembly in .NET?

Tags: c#, project, .net-assembly, signed

Visual Studio 2008(C#).....I have 3 project in one solution(win application). In every project I've been signing using project properties signing tab to one MySigned.snk. How to manage build configuration so my project doesn't error on every build?

I use [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MYproject1, PublicKey=.....")] properties so the other project class can access internal class of base class on other project.

Error becasuse I used backgroundprocess to update every form on my project.But on development environment what suppose I have to do so The project safely on during development? thx before...

Comment: I'm not sure about your problem. Do you get specific signing-errors or do you assume that signing is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I use [assembly:
>   InternalsVisibleTo("MYproject1,
>   PublicKey=.....")] properties so the
>   other project class can access
>   internal class of base class on other
>   project.

This is not related to the issue.

> In every project I've been signing
>   using project properties signing tab
>   to one MySigned.snk. How to manage
>   build configuration so my project
>   doesn't error on every build?

I assume it is because the assembly versions are auto-incrementing:

- Use project references always. This way, you will make sure everything is built against latest version numbers
- Removing * from the AssemblyInfo's assembly version attribute will help here but it is advisable to keep it there.

Comment: Never would get it out of the question! Respect!

Comment: For reference. etc. I have been using the reference project .. and for each of the build process still uses folders Myapp / bin / debug.
 I have not created the environment for the development ... it's using default setting so  AUTOINCREMENT in every project has not yet occurred.
 Thank you for responsenya.i will try to watch assemblyinfo's version attribute.Sorry for out of topic.

Comment: Apologies for my bad wording. I changed *irrelevant* to *not related*.